# Android Sqlite Query union all

Tags: android, sqlite

Below is my code for the query where I am currently passing the ids of only 8 products which exists in the DB table of 100 records.

```
String query = "SELECT productId IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length)+"),"+ " * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE type LIKE 'percent'"
                            + " UNION ALL "
                            + "SELECT productId IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length)+"),"+ " * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE type LIKE 'currency' ORDER BY cash DESC";
                    cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(query, ids);
```

My problem is, it showing all the records (that is all 100 records) instead of only those 8 I am passing from ID using the `IN` clause.
I want these 8 records (or more passed in the function) to be shown `ORDER` by cash.

Now how should I write this query to achieve my goal.

**Edit:**
I am using only one table for this purpose.

Comment: simply: you dont know SQL at all `SELECT productId IN (...)` what? ... `type LIKE 'percent'` (there is no need for `like` if you don't use wildcards)

Comment: I'd not use a `UNION ALL` (which, by the way, includes the duplicates too), but use `"SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Type IN ('percent', 'category') AND productId IN (" +  makePlaceholders(ids.length) + ")"`

Comment: Did my suggested query work? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @DerGol...lum the question you has answered last helped me. And here the problem is not resolved so I just did the whole work with the code instead to be done from DB.

Answer (score 2):

i have never seen sql like this:

```
SELECT productId IN (..) from ... where ....
```

I would expect to see

```
SELECT productId from ... where productId IN (..) and ....
```

Comment: After doing what you said, I get this message: 1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `IN` to the `WHERE` clause like the following.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE type LIKE 'percent' AND " productId IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length)+"),"+ "
                            + " UNION ALL "
                            + "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE type LIKE 'currency' AND productId IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length)+"),"+ " ORDER BY cash DESC";
                    cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(query, ids);
```

Comment: Man this is returning only 3 records

Comment: Can you confirm that the 8 records you are looking for have the `type` column equal to `percent` (since you have no wild card in your `like` statement) in the first table and `type` equals `currency` in the second?

Comment: Maybe posting some example data would help

Comment: This is only one table

Comment: That is not discernible from your question.